# A DRY way of writing similar unit tests in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing, testing

I have some similar unit tests in python.
There are so similar that only one argument is changing.

```
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def test_typeA(self):
        self.assertTrue(foo(bar=TYPE_A))

    def test_typeB(self):
        self.assertTrue(foo(bar=TYPE_B))

    def test_typeC(self):
        self.assertTrue(foo(bar=TYPE_C))

    ...
```

Obviously this is not very DRY, and if you have even 4-5 different options the code is going to be very repetitive

Now I could do something like this

```
class TestFoo(TestCase):
    BAR_TYPES = (
        TYPE_A,
        TYPE_B,
        TYPE_C,
        ...
    )

    def _foo_test(self, bar_type):
        self.assertTrue(foo(bar=bar_type))

    def test_foo_bar_type(self):
        for bar_type in BAR_TYPES:
            _foo_test(bar=bar_type))
```

Which works, however when an exception gets raised, how will I know whether _foo_test failed with argument TYPE_A, TYPE_B or TYPE_C ?

Perhaps there is a better way of structuring these very similar tests?

Comment: it's OK to be repetitive in tests if it keeps them simple and understandable. You don't want to write tests for your tests do you?

Comment: Ive read that in a few places that being repetitive in tests is OK. But then its all just python code. The above example is obviously trivial. Sometimes I might have 5 different systems tests in just one test suite for one `bar_type` and each test could run to 10 lines. So thats 50 lines of code that now has to be copied and pasted X number of times for X number of `bar_type`'s. Then I have to go and edit each 'bar_type` reference by hand. Any any time I add another 'bar_type` i now have to go and copy and paste for hundreds of test just so I can cover another condition. Definitely not DRY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to do is essentially a parameterized test. This feature isn't included in standard django or python unittest modules, but a number of libs provide it: [nose-parameterized](https://github.com/wolever/nose-parameterized), [py.test](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html), [ddt](http://ddt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example.html)

My favorite so far is ddt: it resembles NUnit-JUnit style parameterized tests most, pretty lightweight, don't get in your way and does not require dedicated test runner (like `nose-parameterized` do). The way it can help you is that it modifies test name to include all parameters, so you would clearly see which test case failed by looking at a test name.

With ddt your example would look like this:

```
import ddt

@ddt.ddt
class TestProcessCreateAgencyOfferAndDispatch(TestCase):

    @ddt.data(TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE_C)
    def test_foo_bar_type(self, type):
        self.assertTrue(foo(bar=type))
```

In such case names will look like `test_foo_bar_type__TYPE_A` (technically, it constructs it something like `[test_name]__[repr(parameter_1)]__[repr(parameter_2)]`).

As a bonus, it is much cleaner (no helper method), and you get three methods instead of one. The advantage here is that you can test various code paths in a method and get one test case per each path (but a certain amount of thinking is needed, sometimes it's better to have a dedicated test for some of code paths)

Comment: ddt definitely worked. Although I found nose-parameterized is a bit easier for passing in parameters already defined in a tuple. Thanks John.

Comment: @luke_aus you're welcome. With ddt you can pass parameters defined in a tuple with `@data(*PARAMETERS_TUPLE)` (note asterisk).

Answer (score 0):

Most TestCase assertion methods, including [`assertTrue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue), take an optional `msg` argument.

If you change your `BAR_TYPES` tuple to include the variable names, then you can include this in the message that is shown when the assertion fails.

```
class TestProcessCreateAgencyOfferAndDispatch(TestCase):
    BAR_TYPES = (
        ('TYPE_A', TYPE_A),
        ('TYPE_B', TYPE_B),
        ('TYPE_C', TYPE_C),
        ...
    )

    def _foo_test(self, var_name, bar_type):
        self.assertTrue(foo(bar=bar_type), var_name)

    def test_foo_bar_type(self):
        for (var_name, bar_type) in BAR_TYPES:
            _foo_test(bar=bar_type), var_name=var_name)
```

Comment: Good idea. The issue for me is that if something fails inside the `foo` function before the `self.assertTrue` call then you don't know which `bar_type` test caused it, you just get an error `test_foo_bar_type` failed

Comment: Good point. Including `var_name` means you can debug quicker by adding `print(var_name)` once a test fails, but I agree it's not ideal.